# Making a short video

Tags: video

I'm a beginner  and I want to make a short Video with different layers.

Like showing a  shape later or hiding a shape temporarily. How do I do that?

Could you give me key words to look for a video on this topic?

Comment: Do you mean you want to make objects appear and disappear in an animation?

Comment: I think you might be looking for **Blender Compositing** as good starting search terms

Comment: Maybe you could use the video editor.